# Updating meteor from 1.4.3.2 to 1.5 causes a build error with ecmascript package on MacOS

Tags: meteor

I have updated meteor for the project to 1.5 and have done the following:

1. ran `meteor update`
2. reinstalled `node_modules`
3. ran `meteor reset`

[The relevant github issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/8800)

The error message is:

```
While processing files with ecmascript (for target web.browser): /tools/isobuild/compiler-plugin.js:376:52: Cannot read property 'id' of null

at InputFile.resolve (/tools/isobuild/compiler-plugin.js:376:52)
at InputFile._require (/tools/isobuild/compiler-plugin.js:386:25)
at InputFile.require (/tools/isobuild/compiler-plugin.js:380:17)
at requireWithPrefix (packages/babel-compiler.js:428:32)
at requireWithPath (packages/babel-compiler.js:357:14)
at resolveHelper (packages/babel-compiler.js:330:22)
at packages/babel-compiler.js:306:19
at Array.forEach (native)
at walkHelper (packages/babel-compiler.js:305:22)
at walkBabelRC (packages/babel-compiler.js:295:7)
at resolveHelper (packages/babel-compiler.js:333:11)
at packages/babel-compiler.js:306:19
at Array.forEach (native)
at walkHelper (packages/babel-compiler.js:305:22)
at walkBabelRC (packages/babel-compiler.js:295:7)
at BabelCompiler.BCp._inferHelper (packages/babel-compiler.js:380:3)
at BabelCompiler.BCp._inferFromPackageJson (packages/babel-compiler.js:268:17)
at BabelCompiler.BCp.inferExtraBabelOptions (packages/babel-compiler.js:237:10)
at BabelCompiler.BCp.processOneFileForTarget (packages/babel-compiler.js:166:10)
at BabelCompiler.<anonymous> (packages/babel-compiler.js:109:26)
at Array.forEach (native)
at BabelCompiler.BCp.processFilesForTarget (packages/babel-compiler.js:108:14)
```

Comment: which OS you using? unix / windows?

Comment: Im using MacOS.

Comment: What meteor version were you updating from?

Comment: from version 1.4.3.2